# Running Ubuntu 22.04 on a Blackview Tablet Android 12 Doke OS_P3.0

Tags: android, tablet

I will particularly be using the tablet for it's stylus and wanting to use something like Xournal++ . I have never owned a tablet , but I have been running Ubuntu on my laptops for the past 10 years and love it ! But i need to know that if I purchase the tablet that all will run smoothly including the stylus

Comment: standard tablets do not run anything other than the OS they came with. Most likely this will not work, unless someone already wrote a workaround for it. And very likely the stylus drivers/etc are proprietary and integrated into the existing OS on the tablet, so you can't use them (or it will take a lot of work to decipher/reverse engineer/etc). In short, everything will *not* go smoothly, and most likely won't work at all.

Comment: also not sure what the [wacom] tag is doing there, this is not a Wacom drawing tablet but rather a mobile device running Android...